# No such image: docker.io/openshift/origin-node-problem-detector:v3.11.0

Tags: image, error-handling, openshift, pull, okd

I am trying to install `node-problem-detector` for `OpenShift` but the pod is showing this error.

```
 Warning  Failed   1h (x30 over 3h)    kubelet, server  Error: ErrImagePull
  Normal   Pulling  1h (x31 over 3h)    kubelet, server  pulling image "docker.io/openshift/origin-node-problem-detector:v3.11.0"
  Normal   BackOff  23m (x805 over 3h)  kubelet, server  Back-off pulling image "docker.io/openshift/origin-node-problem-detector:v3.11.0"
  Warning  Failed   4m (x888 over 3h)   kubelet, server  Error: ImagePullBackOff
```

Where is the image now?

Comment: Also have a look on this please: https://github.com/openshift/openshift-ansible/issues/11928

Answer (score 0):

oc describe pod  
Examine the events of the output: ImagePullBackoff error

In your case i think the image can not be pulled from the Internet.

**Debuging steps**:

try to pull the docker image and tag manually on your computer

Identify the node by doing a 'oc get pods -o wide'

ssh into the node (if you can) that can not pull the docker image

check that the node can resolve the DNS of the docker registry by performing a ping.

try to pull the docker image manually on the node

If you are using a private registry, check that your secret exists and the secret is correct. Your secret should also be in the same namespace. Some registries have firewalls that limit ip address access. The firewall may block the pull

Some CIs create deployments with temporary docker secrets. So the secret expires after a few days.

Answer (score 0):

```
repository docker.io/openshift/origin-node-problem-detector not found: does not exist or no pull access
```

I guess that the repo is not available. Or can you pull it?